# How do I fill in a 3d mesh?

Tags: 3d-printing, remesh

I want to 3d print a model I made using [mineways](https://www.realtimerendering.com/erich/minecraft/public/mineways/index.html). The print fails because the model is hollow though and I need to fill it. There is a [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214447/make-a-hollow-minecraft-build-solid) asking for something similar to what I am asking but I want to keep the color of my statue too. I wanted to voxel remesh my object but when I do it comes out solid green.

[image]

Comment: All polygonal models are surface-only .. can you say what you mean by 'hollow', if not that? Maybe even share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here is my blender [file] (https://blend-exchange.com/b/Xyma8DDx). When I say the model is hollow I mean it is empty, I'm new to blender so maybe there is something I'm not getting here. When I tried to print the model, it failed because it was hollow and the roof caved in. Or at least that's what my librarian told me ( I use a library's 3d printer ).

Comment: I have answered my own question. What I did to fill and add support to my model was to import the model in cura. Then I set the infill to 20% and turned on support on trees mode. It's printing now and doesn't seem like it's going to fail.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot 3D print [non-manifold geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry). Go into *Edit Mode* and then menu *Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold*. It will select all non-manifold edges which you have to fix. There are around 100 edges in your model that are non-manifold.

[image]

An object being hollow is not the issue. For as long as your mesh is airtight, it will get printed as a pure solid (wasting a lot of material) like the *Default Cube* on the left unless you have explicitly modeled it to have hollowness like in the below example on the right where you can see it in x-ray mode having thickness inside. Just make sure the Face Normals are facing in the correction direction as seen in the cross-sectional view. So your first option would be to create an interior so it has some thickness which can also save you alot of material when printing.

[image]

The other option is to separate the 2 cubes by giving them their own separate edge which isn't shared. What you can do is select the shared vertex and go into menu *Mesh > Split > Faces & Edges by Vertices*. This will create 6 vertices overlapping each other. To visualize how that looks like I have explicitly moved them apart. You need to join the encircled vertices back together. Just be careful that you don't accidentally merge the 2 resulting merged vertices back together when you do a <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance* operation.

[image]

Unfortunately, it looks like you also have internal faces which is also non-manifold. Read more about [non-manifold geometry here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry).